# GCM notifications with Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am making an android app which I plan to offer for free for a trial period of say, 30 days.
So I am thinking of strategy to implement it.
One commonly used strategy is to have a server side service which would be called when user first installs the application and it saves time of application installation at server.Each time user launches the application, this backend service is called to check how much time has passed since app installation. This strategy is good in the sense that user can't circumvent it by changing device time or uninstalling and reinstalling the app.
But majot disadvantage is that server call on every launch of app may slow down the app and hence bad user experience.

So I came across GCM service provided by Google. So I plan that I call server side service to store instalation time whne app is installed for first time.
No call is made when user launches app afterwards. And when trial period is over, server sends notifications to this effect to GCM server which then notifies device about it.
But I have two concerns regarding it:

1. Can GCM service be used to send notifications to only certain devices and not all on which app is installed OR is notification send to all devices?
2. GCM service needs Google Play Store application installed on device.Is it possible that user uninstalls Google Play Store application and hence stops receiving GCM notifications, thus circumventing the trial period constraint.

Inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) link you will get required information ,,, this is through Google Play Services their is one more way you can directly use the gcm.jar file in your lib folder in that case you won't need Google Play Services

you can register the user through gcm and store the registered user information on your local server with some other information like username on country or device id ... by using this you can set the tag to send notification to specific user.... remember gcm registration doesn't allow to store any tags regarding user at the time of registration...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use latest GCM library.
Steps
1)Add Google-Play-Services library to your project
2)Sign up for GCM from https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

3)Download all files from here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Rxy_fDHdSjXzB4bkJ4WVdNQUk

4)User GCMRegister class to register your devices
5)Add your notification code when it recieved in GCMService
6)Add Service in manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
- <!--  for Gingerbread GSF backward compat 
  --> 
  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" /> 
  <category android:name="com.fudiyo" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
- <service android:name="com.fudiyo.gcmservice.GcmService" android:exported="false">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </service>
```